# Why does selecting an attribute of an Oracle object require an alias?

Tags: oracle, inheritance, oracle-18c

My GIS software has an Oracle 18c object type called [ST_GEOMETRY](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm).

The object type has [attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm):

> The attributes of the spatial type represent the following
> information:
>
> - Entity: The type of geometric feature stored in the spatial column (linestring, multilinestring, multipoint, multipolygon, point, or
>   polygon), the value of which is a bit mask derived from the
>   st_geom_util stored procedure.
> - Numpts: The number of points defining the geometry; for multipart geometries, this includes the separators between each part, one point
>   for each separator.
> - Minx, miny, maxx, maxy: The spatial envelope of the geometry
> - Area: The area of the geometry
> - Len: The perimeter length of the geometry
> - SRID: Contains the identifier for the geometry that links it to its associated spatial reference (coordinate system) record in the
>   ST_Spatial_References table
> - Points: Contains the byte stream of the point coordinates that define the geometry

---

I can select an object's attribute using one of two methods:

1. Use Oracle's [TREAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TREAT.html#GUID-037C0CD3-C256-4A02-80E0-C6F15147C5BF) function.

> ```
> select 
>     treat(shape as sde.st_geometry).numpts as num_points
> from 
>     a_test_table
>
> NUM_POINTS
> ----------
>         37
>        161
> ```

2. Or I can simply use an alias:

> ```
> select 
>     a.shape.numpts as num_points
> from 
>     a_test_table a
>
> NUM_POINTS
> ----------
>         37
>        161
> ```

---

**Question:**

Why is it necessary to use an alias to select an attribute from an Oracle object?

If I were to remove the alias...

```
select 
    shape.numpts as num_points
from 
    a_test_table
```

Then I would get an error:

```
ORA-00904: "SHAPE"."NUMPTS": invalid identifier
```

Comment: [Techniques for selecting an object's attribute](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16835664/#Comment_16835664): *You can also surround the object name in braces/brackets to indicate it's not a table alias:* `select (shape).sdo_gtype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Oracle made it so.

[t_alias](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__T_ALIAS-EF134CB8)

> **t_alias**
>
> Specify a correlation name, which is an alias for the table, view,
> materialized view, or subquery for evaluating the query. **This alias is
> required if the select list references any object type attributes or
> object type methods.** Correlation names are most often used in a
> correlated query. Other references to the table, view, or materialized
> view throughout the query must refer to this alias.

Answer (score 1):

It's a requirement so that the SQL parser recognizes the elements. Without the alias it gets confused with the dot notation. Note that it applies to *all* object types. Not just ST_GEOMETRY or SDO_GEOMETRY.

(I was not aware of the `treat(... as ...)` trick. But then using an alias is still simpler.